# QGIS - how to symbolise trajectory segments by their start time

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a trajectory layer in PostGIS of type LINESTRINGM. I want to visualize it in QGIS and symoblize such that each segment of the trajectory is classified by its start time. the layer field are as follows:

```
trajectory geometry,
tripid text 
min_t timestamp without time zone,  -- start time
max_t timestamp without time zone,  -- end time
pt_cnt numeric  -- no.of points in trajectory
```

What I have done:

I first split the trajectory into its segments by using geometry generator function `segments_to_line` in QGIS.

In the second part I need to style the segments with an expression such that it is symbolized/classified by hour interval on the field `min_t`. Currently I am doing interpolation using `scale_linear` function as below.

```
ramp_color(
  'RdYlBu',
  scale_linear(
   
      hour(min_t)
  ,
    0,24,
    0,1
  )
)
```

But I want to actually define classes as given below. How can i define classes with an expression?

0h - 6h (night)

6h - 12h (morning)

12h to 18h (afternoon)

18h to 24h (evening)

I am totally new to QGIS expression and need help here.